# CSS element reducing performance

Tags: javascript, css

I have problems with google page speed and my nextjs app. Google determines that one of the elements is reducing almost 60% of the page performance. Those elements are just simple colorized elements that are placed as background of the page.
I'm calling them like:

```
<span className={`triangle first`} />
<span className={`triangle second`}/>
<span className={`triangle third`} />
```

and CSS

```
.triangle {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  filter: blur(512px) !important;
  -webkit-filter: blur(512px) !important;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;

  &.first {
    top: -20rem;
    left: -6rem;
    background-color: $primary;
  }

  &.second {
    top: -0rem;
    right: -15rem;
    background-color: $blue;
    transform: rotate(-58deg) skewX(-30deg) scale(1, .866);
  }

  &.third {
    top: 70rem;
    left: -10rem;
    background-color: $green;
    transform: rotate(-130deg);
  }
}
```

I know they are to big and so on, but I don't know how to implement such background the other way. How could I optimize that?

Comment: The biggest perf killer in here is `blur(512px)`. Do you really need that powerful a blur? Gaussian blur is slow to compute, even with a 10px radius that may kill perfs. But with a 512px radius... What are do these look like exactly? You can maybe replace them with a gradient at this scale.

Comment: Small note: that's not CSS (I'm guessing it's Sass), but a 512 pixel blur is going to absolutely be a performance hit. At that point you might as well just use a solid background or background gradient instead. Also, if you don't have classes that come from variables etc, don't use ```<span className={`triangle first`} />```, just use `<span className="triangle first"/>` =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's actual (but not official) CSS: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/#motivation . You can use PostCSS to pretend already.

Comment: Right, so: that's not CSS right now. That's PostCSS. CSS Nesting has been an open issue for over 11 years, that draft's been a draft for over a year and a half, it's great that it exists but doesn't actually mean it'll land into the official spec. It's just "more likely than before" =)

Comment: It's clearly SASS, given that there's variables. No use arguing over a made-up intention of it adhering to a proposed CSS spec.